# In OS Catalina make a account Standard

Tags: macos, administrator, single-user

I have an MacBook Air with the OS Catalina installed. I need to change my admin account to a Standard User account.So how would you change a account from Administrator to a Standard account by using Recovery or Single User Mode, while not creating another admin account.

Comment: Answer updated. If you are looking for ways to remove *all* admin accounts from a Mac, please add some details about which problem you want to solve with this.

Comment: @nohillsideOn my macbook Air, There are two administrator accounts I am looking to delete only one of them.

Comment: See the answer below then :-)

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh11774/10.14/mac/10.14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Recovery/Single User mode for this.

- If you don't have a new admin account yet, create one in System Preferences->Users & Groups
- Log out of the current account (the one you want to switch from admin to standard)
- Log in with another admin account
- Open System Preferences->Users & Groups, select the old account and untick "User can administer the computer"